# Can't listen on ephemeral tcp port

Tags: networking, perl

I have several servers running CentOS 7.2, all installed from a local repo and managed via puppet (so they're very similar).  On most of them, running the following command produces no output (as expected):

```
perl -we 'use AnyEvent::Socket;tcp_server(undef,undef,sub{},sub{})'
```

However, on one particular machine, the same command returns the error:

```
Undefined port for Socket::pack_sockaddr_in at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/AnyEvent/Socket.pm line 549.
```

I've checked that `hostname`, `hostname -f`, and the contents of `/etc/hostname` are all the same.  `/etc/resolv.conf` is correct.

I don't know if the problem only affects Perl (bad/missing module) or if it's a system level problem (bad config).  Suggestions for a similar test in another language welcome.

Comment: The error does not indicate a missing Perl component.  Changing the second undef to 0 works around it, but other hosts don't have this problem and documentation says that undef works the same as 0.